# Angular7 Receive API data before running next function

Tags: angular, asynchronous, httpclient, angular-promise

I would like to receive data from API before running next function in angular7

'data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users'
  async getData() {
    await this.http.get(this.url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(
      res => {return res}
    )
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
  public users
  constructor(private dataservice: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.dataservice.getData()
    console.log(this.users)
    next_function()
    ....
```

Actual print out:
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state: true

Expected print out:
the json object received

I would like to run some function to deal with the data before displaying them in html, so I need to have the data loaded inside the class.

Edit:
Would there be other method except putting the next_function inside the getDATA()?

Comment: Making a function async just means it always returns a promise and you can use await inside it. It doesn't magically make its callers receive the value synchronously, they still have to resolve the promise.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do here is return the Observable from the http call and subscribe to that.

**data.service.ts**

```
    getData() {
     return this.http.get(this.url);
    }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
this.dataservice.getData().subscribe(resp => {
   this.users = resp; // here you set the users
   next_function(); // this function will be called after getting data from the service
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to the promise/async/await recipe, then you can do it this way:

```
// service
getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise();
}

// component
async ngOnInit() {
    this.users = await this.dataservice.getData();
    console.log(this.users);
    next_function();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `async`/`await` here at all. You are already using `toPromise` in `getData` to convert the observable to a promise. You can simply return this promise and handle the rest in the component.

```js
getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise();
}
```

Now use `then` in `ngOnInit` to get the resolved/rejected data.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataservice.getData().then(users => {
        console.log(users);
        next_function();
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

This way if you call `getData` from different components, you can handle any API errors in that component. You may also want to check out [observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables).