# Function doesn't wait for subscribe to get the information

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I am getting the data from firebase saving it in an observable then subscribing to it to extract the data.

In my service i subscribe to an observable to get the data using this method

```
canAddBookmark(item : bookmark){
     let canAdd = true;
      this.bookmarks.subscribe((data)=>{
       alert("First!!!");
      
      for(let i =0;i<data.length;i++){
         if(item.idd==data[i].idd&&item.email==data[i].email){
          
          canAdd=false;
        return canAdd;
      }
      }
      canAdd = true;
    }

    );
    
    return canAdd;
    
    
}
```

Which should return a boolean to a function in another class the function:

```
addBookmark(idd:number){
    let temp:bookmark = {idd:idd,email:this.email};
    
    let val =   this.bookmarkDb.canAddBookmark(temp);

    alert("Second!!!!");
    if(val==true){
      alert("success");
      this.bookmarkDb.addBookmark(temp);
    }
    if(val==false){
    alert("Already book marked");}
  
 
}
```

the alert with "second" comes before "first". is there anyway to make the function wait for the other function to return the boolean.

i tried to play around with async /await i failed tho.

Comment: change it to a promise - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599421/subscription-to-promise

Comment: Check this tread. Hope this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58300488/angular7-receive-api-data-before-running-next-function